# Using Normal Distributions to find Proportion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The height of a randomly selected woman from a population is normal with $\mu=165cm$ and $\sigma=7cm$. The heights f the men in this population are normal with $\mu=178cm$ and $\sigma = 8cm$.

I am asked: **What proportion of the men are shorter than half of the women?**

Since the populations follow two normal distributions, and I am supposed to find the proportion of the men that are shorter than half of the women, I believe I have to find the normal distribution of men area under the curve that occurs before half of women. I think this equates to the probability of lying left of the $z$ score.

I know the formula for calculating the $z$ score is:

$z=\frac{\bar x-M}{\sigma}$

Where $\bar x$ is the mean, and $M$ is the measurement of height, and $\sigma$ is a standard deviation.

However, I am uncertain of what values I should use given to me to substitute into this equation. After I find the $z$ score, I have to use the standard normal distribution table to find the proportion of men that are shorter than half of women.

Sorry if my reasoning sounds confusing, I am very new to this topic and not sure if I am approaching the problem correctly/in the easiest possible way.

Answer (score 1):

I would break this question up into two pieces.  First, what height are half of the women taller than?  Since the mean of the women distribution is $165$ and the median of a normal distribution is its mean, the answer is 165.

The second half of the question is: What proportion of men are less than the height we just calculated. i.e. What proportion of men are less than 165 cm.  That is just asking what is the probability that a normal distribution with mean 178 and standard deviation 8 is less than or equal to 165.  So you need to calculate:

$$P(X \leq 165)$$
where $X$ is the normal distribution for male heights.

Comment: Similar to the question I asked in the other answer to this question, how do we know which number corresponds to $\bar x$ and which corresponds to $M$ ?

Comment: @mnmarkets - Your formula is a bit odd.  Usually you would write: $z = \frac{x - \bar{x}}{\sigma}$.  There $x$ is the outcome you are asking the probability about (e.g. 165 above), $\bar{x}$ is the mean, and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation.

Comment: How do I know to use the standard deviation ($\sigma$)  of men rather than women? I know we are calculating the proportion of men, but is there a more in depth explanation?

Comment: @mnmakrets  They are asking about the distribution (proportion) of men.  The info that describes that is that its a normal distribution with the male mean and standard deviation.

Comment: @mnmakrets - There is nothing really more to it than that.

Answer (score 1):

due to symmetry, half the women are shorter that 165, so you need to calculate $$p(M<165)=p\left(z<\frac{165-178}{8}\right)$$
Can you finish it?

Comment: How do we know to subtract the average height of men from the average height of women, not the other way round?

Comment: is it because we are calculating the proportion of MEN shorter relative to half of women, not the reverse?

Comment: the formula for the normal distribution is $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$, where $x$ is the value of interest, in this case $165$, and $\mu$ is the mean of the distribution of men

Comment: yes to your second question!

Comment: Thank you! What specifically is the value of interest ( variable $x$ )? I can see that for this question it is the mean height of women, but for other questions involving normal distributions, how can I be certain which number corresponds to which variable in a question?

Comment: it's usually some value that the variable **could** be, apart from the mean, but it very much depends on the wording of the question...

Comment: Once I calculate $z$, I know that $p( z \lt -1.625)$. Using a normal distribution table such as the one in the link: http://www.pavementinteractive.org/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/Normal_table.gif   How do I determine which above horizontal value it corresponds to?

Comment: either -1.62 or -1.63 or interpolate (take the average)

Comment: Does the top horizontal row of numbers correspond to the standard deviation for men  ($\sigma = 8cm = 0.08 m$)? If so, will the proportion of men that are shorter than half of the women be equal to $ 0.0465$ ?

Comment: This is if using $z$ as $-1.62$